# Rails: index_by returning nil key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am seeing some strange behavior with `index_by` (or perhaps intended and I'm just not understanding).

```
pry(#<#<Class:0x18c40dc1>>)> permissions[:all]
=> [#<Permission:0x557be464 id: 118, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: 1, profile_type_id: nil, value: "x">,
#<Permission:0x1078d014 id: 120, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: 2, profile_type_id: nil, value: "x">,
#<Permission:0x38a840bb id: 122, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: 3, profile_type_id: nil, value: "x">,
#<Permission:0x1c8b4fc9 id: 124, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: 4, profile_type_id: nil, value: "x">,
#<Permission:0x43e0e354 id: 126, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: 5, profile_type_id: nil, value: "x">,
#<Permission:0x07381c77 id: 128, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: 6, profile_type_id: nil, value: "x">,
#<Permission:0x418bfe5e id: 130, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: 7, profile_type_id: nil, value: "x">,
#<Permission:0x05355f78 id: 191, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: 29, workflow_id: nil, profile_type_id: nil, value: "w">,
#<Permission:0x66d3687d id: 198, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: 60, workflow_id: nil, profile_type_id: nil, value: "r">,
#<Permission:0x214f0b74 id: 207, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: 61, workflow_id: nil, profile_type_id: nil, value: "r">,
#<Permission:0x3fa8680d id: 220, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: nil, profile_type_id: 1, value: "e">,
#<Permission:0x10493e1f id: 221, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: nil, profile_type_id: 2, value: "c">]

pry(#<#<Class:0x18c40dc1>>)> permissions[:all].class
=> Permission::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation
```

When I call `permissions[:all].index_by(&:profile_type_id)`, I recive a object that has a `nil` `profile_type_id`.

```
pry(#<#<Class:0x18c40dc1>>)> permissions[:all].index_by(&:profile_type_id)
=> {nil=>#<Permission:0x214f0b74 id: 207, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: 61, workflow_id: nil, profile_type_id: nil, value: "r">,
 1=>#<Permission:0x3fa8680d id: 220, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: nil, profile_type_id: 1, value: "e">,
 2=>#<Permission:0x10493e1f id: 221, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: nil, profile_type_id: 2, value: "c">}
```

**Question:**

Why am I receiving that first `permission` object with no `profile_type_id`? Also, if it is returning values with `nil` `profile_type_id`, why doesn't it return the other objects with a `nil` for `profile_type_id`?

Also, in testing I found `inject` does the same thing.

```
pry(#<#<Class:0x18c40dc1>>)> permissions[:all].inject({}){|hash, val| hash.merge(val.profile_type_id => val)}
=> {nil=>#<Permission:0x214f0b74 id: 207, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: 61, workflow_id: nil, profile_type_id: nil, value: "r">,
 1=>#<Permission:0x3fa8680d id: 220, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: nil, profile_type_id: 1, value: "e">,
 2=>#<Permission:0x10493e1f id: 221, role_id: 2, ne_attribute_id: nil, workflow_id: nil, profile_type_id: 2, value: "c">}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because an index is normally unique. You are indexing by profile_type_id, which have 3 unique values: 1, 2, nil.

Among all the records that have profile_type_id = nil, only the last one is returned.

Comment: Just as a note, if you want to get arrays of all the items with a particular profile_id, you can use `group_by` instead of `index_by`.